# Setting up staging area

Tags: customization

I typically work on live sites, no matter the scope. What is the best way to set up a staging/dev area for live wp sites?

I know MAMP is the way to go, but how would this work? Would I have to download a database everytime and then export? Seems cumbersome.

Comment: Better safe than sorry, you should look into investing in learning version control as well, I like git.

Comment: version control being in addition to and different from Git?

Comment: Git being a method of version control

Comment: I think walk before you can run. Git can wait.

Comment: Fair enough @vancover, but even after doing this for something like six years now, I still make enough typos, misclicks and flat out brain farts that working on live sites for anything other than static text content updates is just asking for it.

Comment: that's what I thought, just making sure. Been using git hub for a bit then dropped it now back on it, so I think that makes sense to me.

Comment: The Codex page [Running a Development Copy of WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress) has had some recent updates.